# Is it possible to specify a function with both extern and override modifiers?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I'm trying to override the behavior of an external function in `user32.dll` because I don't want a certain window to show up.

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public extern override IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hMenu, bool bRevert)
    {
        return new IntPtr();
    }
```

but this won't work because I get the following errors:

> ... no suitable method found to override

and

> ... cannot be extern and declare a body

Is there any way to simulate what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the source code that calls `GetSystemMenu` is within your control then you can provide an alternative `GetSystemMenu` which delegates to the real one most of the time, but does something different for your special case.

If the source code that calls `GetSystemMenu` is outside your control then you will need to use hooks. In this situation you need to modify how `user32.GetSystemMenu` behaves which is entirely outside your codebase.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem stems from the fact that you're illegally adding an implementation to an external method declaration.

The C# specification (10.6.7 External methods) states that:

> Because an external method declaration
>   provides no actual implementation, the
>   method-body of an external method
>   simply consists of a semicolon. An
>   external method may not be generic.